# How to manage data dependencies between raw objects?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, coffeescript

Consider the following situation:

```
items = [
  {
    id: 1
    attributes: [
      { key: a, value: 2 }
      { key: b, value: 3 }
    ],
    requirements: null
  }
  {
    id: 2
    attributes: [
      { key: b, value: 2 }
    ],
    requirements: a > 2
  }
  {
    id: 3
    attributes: [
      { key: a, value: 1 }
      { key: c, value: 1 }
    ],
    requirements: a > 1 and b > 2
  }
  {
    id: 4
    attributes: [
      { key: a, value: 2 }
      { key: d, value: 7 }
    ],
    requirements: b > 5 and h < 10
  }
]
```

The expected result, adding together (sum) the various `attributes` is:

```
result = [
  { key: a, value: 3 }
  { key: b, value: 5 }
  { key: c, value: 1 }
]
```

As you can observe, there are dependencies (`requirements`) between objects in the list. In particular, the object with `id: 4` (last one of the series) is discarded from the calculation since the condition `b > 5 and h < 10` is never checked. On the contrary, the object with `id: 2`, initially discarded, then falls in the calculation as a result of the object with `id: 3` (which, by adding 1 to the attribute `a`, makes true the condition `a > 2`).

**What is the algorithm needed to obtain the required result having N objects?**

*Disclaimer: the proposed structure is only an example. You can suggest any changes you believe to achieve the result. I'm working in JavaScript (CoffeeScript) programming language, but any other will be okay.*

Comment: Do you have time or space complexity requirements?  The obvious solution would be `O(n^2)` - did you discard this option?  Also, you will need some way to store the requirements (your current code will evaluate them to a boolean when `items` is instantiated, so they can't be rechecked.  Have you solved this problem, or is it also part of your question?

Comment: @AaronDufour The evaluation of `requirements` key is not intended to be done on object instantiation but on-the-fly whenever is called the `sum` method; I think it is necessary to establish some sort of link between each item's requirement conditions and the `sum` process (an event-driven approach?): each object should listen for changes in the array (item add/remove) and, if the conditions are met, changes its status in `active=true` (or something like that). Then the list object re-executes `sum` again, eventually causes other object to activate, and so on. In any case it's just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by getting the data in a format we can use.  We need to be able to test requirements at will, instead of only when the data object is instantiated:

```
  {
    id: 4
    attributes: [
      { key: a, value: 2 }
      { key: d, value: 7 }
    ],
    requirements: (sum) -> sum.b > 5 and sum.h < 10
  }
```

While we're at it, let's get the attributes in a more useful state (note that this isn't strictly necessary, but makes everything simpler):

```
  {
    id: 4
    attributes: {
      a: 2
      d: 7
    },
    requirements: (sum) -> sum.b > 5 and sum.h < 10
  }
```

Now I'll go through the naive algorithm, which is simplest and should fit your needs.  Essentially, we'll keep looping over the data set, testing each one that hasn't been used yet and adding it to the sum if it passes.

```
changed = true
sum = {}
init(sum, items)
while changed
    changed = false
    for item in items
        if !item.used && item.requirements(sum)
            add(sum, item.attributes)
            changed = true
            item.used = true
```

I'll let you fill in the `add` and `init` functions.  The `add` one should be simple; it adds each element in the second parameter to each element in the first.  The `init` needs to set each element in `sum` that may be used (tested or added to) to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions and detailed explanation. I began testing an event-driven implementation to solve this problem but your approach is undoubtedly more clever and elegant. So less code, less complexity. Thanks again.